# Capturing server console in Meteor App

Tags: meteor

We have a meteor app deployed to Digital Ocean. We keep it running using tmux.

There have been times where we have had an issue, and it would be helpful to have a look at the server console.

Is there someway we can store/send the server logs/console while we figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using digital ocean, then you must be using forever js, 
instead of that you can use pm2 which automately keeps a track of logs, 
so if you want to see logs "pm2 logs" which will give all logs, 
now second question comes if I want to see them on a browser, 
you can use https://github.com/nicolsondsouza/meteorshell 
another meteor js app on the server, 
which will help you to see the logs and deploy the app directly without ssh 
I have already done this, on several Digital Ocean server.

Comment: we were using tmux. I think switching to forever seems to be the best way to do it.

Comment: use mup to deploy which is the best way to deploy on custom domain https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up